# WPF Load Tab Content only when tab is selected

Tags: wpf

I Have WPF App...

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <usercontrol1 />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Security" >
          <usercontrol2 />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Details" >
          <usercontrol3 />
       </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

by default all user control are loaded when I view page , I Need To Load each user control only when the tab is clicked and active .
how can I achieve this behavior? thank you .

Comment: If you use mvvm you can virtualise your tab control. Bind a collection of viewmodels. Define one or more datatemplates for them. Only the visible tab content will be instantiated.

Comment: TabControl only has a single content host (to display the selected tab). Not sure what you mean. There can only be a single tab content rendered by default.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the UserControl's Loaded event?

Comment: If you define the items in xaml like in the post then they're all created when the parent view is created.  Not difficult to imagine something expensive happening for each. Spreading that out could well mean  the parent view is up and usable quicker.

Answer (score 0):

> by default all user control are loaded when I view page

They are not actually loaded by only instantiated when the XAML is processed.

Move any code that you don't want to run initially out of the constructors and you should be fine.

If you don't want the controls to be instantiated (created) upfront, you need to remove the elements form the XAML markup and create them on demand, for example in a `SelectionChanged` event handler.